# Mouse is selecting wrong object in Chrome with CKEditor in a Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, modal-dialog, ckeditor

I am building an HTML web page, I encountered into a problem. To reproduce it, I put a CKEditor (jQuery plugin for editing text) inside a Bootstrap modal and give the css {direction:rtl;} to the body.
 In Chrome (Firefox/IE works fine) when the height of the windows is small (ie top & down of the modal reaches the border of main window) and you entered a long text so the CKEditor's scrollbar appears, problem begin to arises by the modal shifting to right and from then the mouse clicks do not hit the target under it very well. If you want to click any of the objects inside modal, you should click to the left of that object.(see picture)
[image: Mouse is selecting wrong object]

(CKEditor :4.5.6  Bootstrap:3.3.5  Chrome: 48.0.2564.97)


*I don`t know why the CKEditor in below snippet is disabled , but you can see the problem if you copy & paste this code to an HTML file:*

```css
body {
            direction: rtl;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>

<body>
    <a href="#dialog1" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-default">بیا</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="dialog1" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>متن برای ترجمه:</h4>
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="#">
                        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="inputText" id="inputText"></textarea>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>

</body>
```

please help me what is the problem.

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I see when I run the code snippet. Looks fine.

[image]

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. as I wrote:"I don`t know why the CKEditor in below snippet is disabled , but you can see the problem if you copy & paste this code to an HTML file" then you should enter such a long Text so the editor's scrollbar apears.